# Conditions for second-degree stochastic dominance for uniform distributions

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

Currently I am reviewing first- and second-degree stochastic dominance. Suppose that we have two uniform distributions $$F^1(y) = \frac{y - a_1}{b_1 - a_1}$$ and 
$$F^2(y) = \frac{y - a_2}{b_2 - a_2}$$ and we only know that $a_1 < a_2$ and $b_2 < b_1$. Based on that information alone, can we retrieve some information concerning 2nd-degree stochastic dominance? Since the two distributions cross there is obviously now first-order stochastic dominance. Does there exist some ratio between the differences $a_2 - a_1$ or $b_1 - b_2$ s.t. we could guarantee second-degree stochastic dominance of one distribution?